# Python: extract all sub-strings in between tags within string

Tags: python, html, string, parsing, tags

I have a large string in the format of the following:

```
'324/;.ke5 efwef dwe,werwrf <>i want this<> ergy;'56\45,> thu ;lokr<>i want this<> htur ;''\> htur> jur'
```

i know that i can do something along the lines of:

```
result= text.partition('<>')[-1].rpartition('<>')[0]
```

but this will just give me what is in between the first <> and the last <> in the string , how can i loop through the whole string and extract what is in between each respective <> <> tag pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and `findall()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "324/;.ke5 efwef dwe,werwrf <>i want this<> ergy;'56\45,> thu ;lokr<>i want this<> htur ;''\> htur> jur"
>>> re.findall(r"<>(.*?)<>", s)
['i want this', 'i want this']
```

where `(.*?)` is a capturing group that would match any characters any number of times in a [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) mode.

Comment: Hi i tired using your method and it worked at first but then i tried using it to find everything within a '\/\/' tag and i stopped working, do you know why this is? @alecxe

Comment: @abcla I think this can and should qualify as a separate question. Consider posting if you need help - make sure to provide all the details. To close this topic, consider accepting the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `string.split()` is what you want:

```
>>> text = """'324/;.ke5 efwef dwe,werwrf <>i want this<> ergy;'56\45,> thu ;lokr<>i want this<> htur ;''\> htur> jur'"""
>>> print text.split('<>')[1:-1]
['i want this', " ergy;'56%,> thu ;lokr", 'i want this']
```

The `split()` method gives you a list of strings where the argument is used as the delimiter. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)  Then, `[1:-1]` gives you a slice of the list without the first and last elements.